# undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE when importing sklearn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

After successfully installing /illumina/thirdparty/python/python-2.7.5/bin/pip2.7 install -U scikit-learn I have problems launching regression analysis. 
`from sklearn import linear_model`  gives

```
File "/illumina/thirdparty/python/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .logistic import (LogisticRegression, LogisticRegressionCV,
  File "/illumina/thirdparty/python/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..svm.base import _fit_liblinear
  File "/illumina/thirdparty/python/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC, \
  File "/illumina/thirdparty/python/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import _fit_liblinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "/illumina/thirdparty/python/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear
ImportError: /illumina/thirdparty/python/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/libsvm.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_inf
```

Seems like the issue is with libsvm as `from sklearn import datasets` works well.

Any suggestions will be most appreciated.

Environment:

- Python 2.7.5
- GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)
- scipy 0.16.0
- numpy 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly an ABI mismatch. You probably are involuntarily using a python module that is linked against a native library that should be of a different version. Make sure there's only one libsvm to be found by your system when you run python.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to uninstall sklearn first.
     apt-get remove sklearn
2. Delete previous sklearn directory created in packages folder
3. Install again
   apt-get install python-sklearn